# VBA CountIf using R1C1 and text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to have a formula display the number or occurrences of the previous row of column "C" (RC3).

An ideal result would look like:

Count: 3

If there were 3 occurrences of the value in the previous row.

The following code returns "False".

`y.FormulaR1C1 = "Count: " + "=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range(R3C3:R" & LR & "C3), " = "&R[-1]C3)"`

y is a cell

LR is the last row

Thanks, and let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a formula in a cell that begins with text - you would need to have the formula in one cell, say A1, and have B1 read `=Count: A1` .  Can you try testing the formula by itself and see if it works?  Your concatenation also looks off at `" = "&`, but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do. Quick example, `"Here is my first string, " & "And here is another.  And 1 + 1 = " & 1 + 1 & "."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CountIf Function is never going to count anything as long as it's inside a test string. And you don't need 'Application.WorksheetFunction' in a cell formula (only if you want to use that function entirely in VBA). Also you don't need a range function in an Excel formula. Try this:

```
y.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Count: ""&CountIf(R3C3:R" & LR & "C3,R[-1]C3)"
```

Though if there is nothing between your search range and your criteria cell, you could eliminate LR altogether with:

```
y.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Count: ""&CountIf(R3C3:R[-2]C3,R[-1]C3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a formula that combines TEXT and builtin functions, use `=CONCATENATE()`. consider the example below:

[image: sameple data]

If you are to use VBA to fill in formula with relative location (`.FormulaR1C1`), it would be:

```
=CONCATENATE("Count: ",COUNTIF(R[-5]C:R[-2]C,"=" &R[-1]C))
```